# Every iteration of the game I want it to reduce the life time by 1

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I have an arraylist which stores different objects about the universe (planet, comet, star etc). Instead of doing this:

```
planet.decreaseLifeTime(1);
star.decreaseLifeTime(1);
comet.decreaseLifeTime(1);
```

Every iteration of the game I want it to reduce the life time by 1. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
private ArrayList<SpaceObject> universeEntities;

public void reduceLifeTime() {
    for (SpaceObject entity: universeEntities) {
        entity.decreaseLifeTime(1);
        if(entity.getLifeTime() <= 0) {
            erase(entity);
            System.out.println("This entity has been erased");
        }

        System.out.println("life time: " + entity.getLifeTime());
    }
}
```

Objects are added like so:

```
planet = new Planet(500, 500, -2, -2, 25, Color.BLUE, this);
universeEntities.add(planet);
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Does the line `erase(entity)` change the `universeEntities` list?

Comment: it only subtracts 1  being the life time (which is an integer) once. whereas, i want it to continually subtract 1 until it gets to 0.

Comment: `while (entity.getLifetime() > 0) { ... }`

Comment: surround that by a loop

Comment: show your complete code,

Comment: Well, not "complete code", but a [mcve]

Comment: I tried surrounding it by a while loop but the game just freezes because i want to put the method reduceLifeTime() in my main loop which is a while loop

Comment: The freezing of your game most likely happens because your added while loop never exits. If your method decreases the lifetime of all objects in the list by 1 that should be fine. Try writing a test, that creates an arraylist with multiple Planet objects. Then call your `reduceLifeTime` method by either writing multiple method calls or putting the call in a loop. Make sure to set the lifetime of all of your planets to less than the amount you are calling your method and look if your list is empty after the run. Also look at @leumas95 answer and fix that part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If `erase(entity)` is modifying the universeEntities list java will get mad.

You can either store the SpaceObject you want to erase in a separate list and then erase them after the for loop.

or

You can loop over the universeEntities without using an iterator 
e.g. a numerical index

Comment: This is a mistake i made when i started programming and i still occasionally forget that removing an item messes up the iteration cycle. But please elaborate what is wrong with the way he is doing the erasing and what exactly makes Java "mad" about it.

Comment: According to the Java API documentation [API 2014] the behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress.

Comment: This is especially important when deleting the entry your iterator currently points to. Almost every implementation of an iterable will have a problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

According to your implementation of the `reduceLifeTime` method, the problem may be in calling `erase` method in it (depends how it is implemented).

If `erase` method just tries to remove an item from `universeEntities` collection by calling ArrayList's [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) method it just break an iterator.

Consider reimplementing your method to:

```
public void reduceLifeTime() {
    Iterator<SpaceObject> iterator = universeEntities.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SpaceObject object = iterator.next();
        object.decreaseLifeTime(1);

        if(object.getLifeTime() <= 0) {
            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println("This entity has been erased.");
        }

        System.out.println(String.format("Life time: %d", object.getLifeTime()));
    }
}
```

---

Fully working sample:

```
public class Test {
    private ArrayList<SpaceObject> universeEntities = new ArrayList<SpaceObject>();

    public Test() {
        universeEntities.add(new Planet());
        universeEntities.add(new Planet());
    }

    public void reduceLifeTime() {
        Iterator<SpaceObject> iterator = universeEntities.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SpaceObject object = iterator.next();
            object.decreaseLifeTime(1);

            if(object.getLifeTime() <= 0) {
                iterator.remove();
                System.out.println("This entity has been erased.");
            }

            System.out.println(String.format("Life time: %d", object.getLifeTime()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();

        while(true) {
            test.reduceLifeTime();
            // Endless loop. Need a quit condition.
        }
    }

    public static class SpaceObject {
        protected int life = 0;

        public SpaceObject(int life) {
            this.life = life;
        }

        public void decreaseLifeTime(int value) {
            this.life -= value;
        }

        public int getLifeTime() {
            return life;
        }
    }

    public static class Planet extends SpaceObject {
        public Planet() {
            super(10);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you do not want to use iterators you can collect items that should be removed in some kind of collection, return from `reduceLifeTime` method and remove using `removeAll` afterwards.